# How to create bar graph highchart based on subject or email_id?

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts, yii2, chart.js

I want to make email sending report using highchart. [This is the chart that i've already create.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zdu05.png)

The 18,19, 20... is the email_id. So the chart show all of the email report. But i want to show the chart per email_id.

report.php

```
<?php

use dosamigos\highcharts\HighCharts;
use backend\models\Email;

$this->title = 'Megablast Statistics';

foreach($dreport as $values) { 
    $a[0]= ($values['email_id']);
    $c[]= ($values['email_id']); 
    $b[]= array('type'=> 'column', 'name' =>$values['email_id'], 'data' => array((int)$values['number_of_recipient'], 
(int)$values['number_of_delivery'],(int)$values['number_of_open'], (int)$values['number_of_click'], (int)$values['number_of_complain'], (int)$values['number_of_bounces']) ); 
}

echo

Highcharts::widget([
    'clientOptions' => [
         'chart'=>[
               'type'=>'pie'
         ],
         'title' => ['text' => 'Megablast Statistics'],
         'xAxis' => [
               'categories' => ['number_of_recipient', 'number_of_delivery', 'number_of_open', 'number_of_click', 'number_of_complain', 'number_of_bounces']
         ],
         'yAxis' => [
               'title' => ['subject' => '']
         ],
         'series' => $b
     ]
]);
```

EmailController.php

```
public function actionReport()
{

    $data = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('select email_id,
                 number_of_recipient,
                 number_of_delivery,
                 number_of_open,
                 number_of_click,
                 number_of_complain,
                 number_of_bounces
                 from email

                 group by email_id')->queryAll();
                 //print_r($data);
                 return $this->render('report', [
                     'dreport' => $data 
                 ]);
}
```

[This is the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VJTC.png)

Thank you :)

Comment: there is nothing provided by you related to the bar graphs where is your code for the HighChart widget?

Comment: im sorry, i have already edit it :) @MuhammadOmerAslam

Comment: It's because you set whole array of series to `series` key in chart configuration object, but instead of that you need to assign only the one series from the array, for example by checking it's `email_id`.

Comment: how to define the series by checking the email_id? @daniel_s

Comment: You are setting the series for all the emails together in the for each loop, if you want to show the charts according to the emails you should filter out the emails and show the chart for them separately, what is in the `$dreport` ?

Comment: $dreport contains variable that refers to $data and $value @MuhammadOmerAslam

Comment: Yes, we know that, but we need to see the structure of mentioned variable.

Comment: I'm totally new at highchart. I get these code from tutorial in the internet. But as I know, the $dreport used to get the data from database using the attribute name. $dreport is the value of the charts. I create them in array because the attribute consist of more than 2 attribute. Please see my database structure on the above link again :) @daniel_s

Comment: I'm not the PHP expert, and as I said before, you're assigning all series arrays instead of specific one (basing on `email_id` field), so you've got the answer and now you need to refactor your code so that the `$b` would be only one object.